# web.config setting equivalent to htaccess Header set Content-disposition

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, iis, web-config

In order to download PDFs as files without opening from the server, I am using a nice script [download.js](http://pixelscommander.com/en/javascript/javascript-file-download-ignore-content-type/) which works brilliantly in Chrome.  But as the author warns in FF it opens a downloaded PDF in a separate tab - causing navigation issues with my SPA.

He says on Apache this code in htaccess will fix it.  My app runs on IIS 8.  I would prefer to handle it in the apps web.config if possible.  What can I put in system.webServer in my Web.config and/or manage in my IIS - shared host provider allowed. (will add pdf to FilesMatch in code below, of course.)

```
//Easiest way to configure headers via Apache is to set Header set Content-Disposition "attachment" for files you want to be downloaded.
//So .htaccess can look like:

<FilesMatch "\.(zip|rar)$">
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this found on [serverfaut](https://serverfault.com/questions/320450/conditionally-set-content-disposition-header) (didn't know about that site before) I was able to put together an outbound rule that is the equivalent of the htaccess language in my question above.  (and learned some wonderful stuff along the way)  I now get the Firefox download behavior I was looking for, though I still need to figure out the best way to handle a resource not found error - suggestions welcome.

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="Allow pdfs to be downloaded" preCondition="Only match pdfs">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Content_Disposition" pattern="(.*)" negate="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="attachment" replace="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^download" />
      </conditions>
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
      <preCondition name="Only match pdfs">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^application/pdf" />
      </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```